# USB C Mod not working with high wattage PD cables

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c

I made a USB C mod for my calculator. I wired all the Vbus, ground, D+, and D- pins to the corresponding mini B traces. Also did the 5.1K resistor as a pd from CC to ground so that USB C to C would work as well. The calculator works with USB A to C and USB C to C but when I use a USB C to C 100W cable it does not work. Any ideas why?

First image is just the mod itself, second image is with a standard USB C to C cable, third image is with an Anker 100W USB C to C cable

Here is the more info about the basic usb c connector breakout board I bought if needed:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001035781660.html

[image: USB C port and wiring.]

[image: USB C to C cable plugged into calculator working]

[image: 100W USB C to C cable not working]

Comment: You forgot to say who is supplying the power.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I used a 90w USB C charger and also the USB C Anker 20k mah power bank. Regardless of what is supplying the power, the 100w cable still won't work with it. A standard USB C to C cable will though.

Comment: Do you have two separate 5.1K resistors for CC1 and CC2?

Comment: I do not, I have one resister for both cc1 and cc2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only showing one resistor on your USB C receptacle board.

For a proper USB C receptacle configuration, you need a resistor per CC pin.

Inside an USB C able with a configuration chip, one of the CC lines gets connected between both devices, and the cable presents a low value resistor on both sides on the other CC pin.

Because your USB C breakout board has both USB CC lines connected to each other, the detection signal is coming into the breakout board via 1 CC pin, and then going out though the other, instead of properly seeing the 5.1k identification resistor.

It works with 60W 2.0 USB C to C cables, since they do not have a chip inside the cable, so the short on your board does not interfere with the operation

Make sure to wire it up so that you have an distinct 5.1k resistor for each CC of the receptacle, instead of trying to save on 1 part and combining the CC pins of the receptacle.

For reference, this is how termination is shown in the USB C specification: (Rd = 5.1k 20%, Ra = the resistor inside your active cable)

[image: USB C being terminated with 2 resistors, each on a different CC line]

Comment: Thanks, I do indeed have just one resistor to both cc pins. When I give each of the cc pins its own resistor, would I have to sever the connection between the two cc pins as well?

Comment: @DairyIce Looking at the aliexpress link of your board, it seems like they did not understand the USB C specification fully, and just connected both pins together before the resistor. You would need to sever the connection between both CC pins and make sure they have their own resistor

Answer (score 0):

> but when I use a USB C to C 100W cable it does not work. Any ideas
> why?

Here is one idea: USB-C cables are getting complicated these days. Special so-called "SOP" processors are built into the cable's overmold, with the purpose to communicate to PowerDelivery devices the exact capabilities of the cable. If a power provider has Power Delivery functions, it will negotiate with PD information that is provided by more than "a regular cable", like yours "100W cable". If power contract is not negotiated due to capabilities mismatch or something, the charger might reject the connection. Technically, the link should drop to basic "safe mode", but who knows, PD is complicated. You need a PD analyzer to get the answer, many-many variants are possible.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the functionality of USB c communications. I too have been wondering why it still doesn't work but others have suggested that I have a resistor per cc pin so that might just be the solution.